# SvnSharp's SvnLookClient changed item actions explanation

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

The property Action of an SvnChangedEventArgs is of type SvnChangeAction enum, but I can't find what each enum value means.
The possible values are None, Add, Delete, Modify and Replace.

I tested and found that:

- Add is when a new item is added or is the destination of a move or copy.
- Deleted is when a item is deleted or is the source of a move.
- Replace is when a item is modified and a new revision of this item is created.

I can suppose that None is used when a item that has not changed is listed because of the svnlook arguments.

I can't find the explanation for Modify value. It's the same as Replace? When it occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Modified is when the contents of the file have been changed.
- Replace is when the file itself has been replaced with another file.
- None is when nothing happened, this normally should not happen. The reason this is here is because it is recommended by the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2004/05/18/134208.aspx) (search for "none")